# C++ axis-aligned rectangle manipulation vectors and strings

Tags: c++, string, class, vector

Hey so I'm having trouble with my C++ homework assignment and I've spent a lot of time working on it trying to figure out my errors. The homework asks you to write a program that reads in user input rectangles. The program will ask for the name of the rectangle starting with rec "name" (i.e. rectangle "John" will be input as rec John), the coordinates of the bottom left corner, the length of the rectangle, and the height of the rectangle. The program will put this in a list and keep asking for more rectangles until the user inputs the name of the rectangle as "stop." The program will give back the input info for each rectangle, and then scale the rectangle by 3. It will give back the scaled rectangle's new bottom left corner coordinate, the midpoint, the area of the rectangle, the perimeter, the height, and the length.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    double px;
    double py;

public:
    void setX(const double x);
    void setY(const double y);
    double getX() const;
    double getY() const;
};

class Rectangle
{
private:
    string name;
    Point blPoint;
    double length, height;

public:
    void setName(const string & inName);
    void setBottomLeft(const double x, const double y);
    void setDimensions(const double inLength, const double inHeight);

    string getName() const;
    Point getBottomLeft() const;
    double getLength() const;
    double getHeight() const;

    double area() const;
    double perimeter() const;
    Point midPoint() const;
    void scaleBy3();
    void display() const;
};
void welcome();
bool read_rect (const string promptName, const string errInvalidName, const string errUsedName, string & inName, vector<Rectangle> & list);
void readXYcoord (const string promptPointxy, double & xcord, double & ycord);
void readLH (const string promptLH, double & inLength, double & inHeight);
void addRect (const string Name, double x, double y, double inLength, double inHeight, vector<Rectangle> & list);
void dis_rec(vector<Rectangle> & list);

int main()
{

    Rectangle rec;
    vector<Rectangle>list;
    string prompt1stName = "Enter the name of the first rectangle: ";
    string promptName = "Enter the name of the next rectangle: ";
    string errInvalidName = "Invalid input. Type 'rec' following by the name or 'stop' if done.";
    string errUsedName = "This name is already being used!";
    string inName;
    string Name;

    double x,y,length,height;

    welcome ();
    bool read = read_rect (prompt1stName, errInvalidName, errUsedName, inName, list);

    while (read == false)
    {
        cout << "Try again! ";
        read = read_rect (prompt1stName, errInvalidName, errUsedName, inName, list);
    }

    if (inName != "stop")
    {
        int a = inName.length() - 4;
        Name = inName.substr(4,a);

        double x, y;
        string promptPointxy = "Enter " + Name + "'s bottom left x and y coords: ";
        readXYcoord (promptPointxy, x, y);

        double length, height;
        string promptLH= "Enter " + Name + "'s length and height: ";
        readLH (promptLH, length, height);

        addRect(Name, x, y, length, height, list);
    }

    while (inName !="stop")
    {
        cout << "Thank you! ";
        bool read = read_rect(promptName, errInvalidName, errUsedName, inName, list);

        while (read == false)
        {
            cout << "Try again! " <<endl;
            read = read_rect(promptName, errInvalidName, errUsedName, inName, list);
        }

        if (inName != "stop")
        {
            int a = inName.length() - 4;
            Name = inName.substr(4, a);

            double x, y;
            string promptPoint = "Enter " + Name + "'s bottom left x and y coords: ";
            readXYcoord(promptPoint, x, y);

            double inLength, inHeight;
            string promptLength = "Enter " + Name + "'s length and height: ";
            readLH(promptLength, inLength, inHeight);

            addRect(Name, x, y, inLength, inHeight, list);
        }
    }

    if (list.size() != 0)
    {
        dis_rec(list);
    }

    else
    {

        cout << "You have no rectangles in your list." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void welcome()
{
    cout << "Welcome! Create your own list of rectangles." << endl;
    cout << "You will be asked to provide information about each rectangle in your list by name." << endl;
    cout << "Type the word 'stop' for the rectangle name when you are done." << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

bool read_rect (const string promptName, const string errInvalidName, const string errUsedName, string & inName, vector<Rectangle> & list)
{
    cout << promptName;
    getline(cin, inName);
    if (inName == "stop")
    {
        return (true);
    }
    else if (inName.substr(0,4) != "rec ")
    {
        cout<< errInvalidName <<endl;
        return (false);
    }
    else
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (inName == "rec " + list[i].getName())
            {
                j = j+1;
            }
        }
        if (j == 0)
        {
            return(true);
        }
        if (j != 0)
        {
            cout << errUsedName;
            return(false);
        }
    }
}

void readXYcoord (const string promptPointxy, double & xcord, double & ycord)
{
    cout << promptPointxy;
    cin >> xcord;
    cin >> ycord;
}

void readLH (const string promptLH, double & inLength, double & inHeight)
{
    cout<< promptLH;
    cin >> inLength;
    cin >> inHeight;
    cout << endl;
    while (inLength <= 0 || inHeight <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Make length and height positive values. Try again.";
        cout << promptLH;
        cin >> inLength;
        cin >> inHeight;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void addRect (const string Name, double x, double y, double inLength, double inHeight, vector<Rectangle> & list)
{
    Rectangle rec;
    rec.setName(Name);
    rec.setBottomLeft(x, y);
    rec.setDimensions(inLength, inHeight);
    list.push_back(rec);
}

void dis_rec(vector<Rectangle> & list)
{
    cout<<"You have "<<list.size()<<" rectangle(s) in your list: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"Rectangle '"<<list[i].getName()<<"': ";
        list[i].display();
        cout<<"After scale by 3:";
        list[i].scaleBy3();
        list[i].display();
    }
}
void Point::setX(const double x)
{
    px = x;
}

void Point::setY(const double y)
{
    py = y;
}

double Point::getX() const
{
    return (px);
}

double Point::getY() const
{
    return (py);
}

void Rectangle::setName(const string & inName)
{
    name = inName;
}

void Rectangle::setBottomLeft(const double x, const double y)
{
    blPoint.setX(x);
    blPoint.setY(y);
}

void Rectangle::setDimensions(const double inLength, const double inHeight)
{
    length = inLength;
    height = inHeight;
}

string Rectangle::getName() const
{
    return (name);
}

Point Rectangle::getBottomLeft() const
{
    return (blPoint);
}

double Rectangle::getLength() const
{
    return (length);
}

double Rectangle::getHeight() const
{
    return (height);
}

double Rectangle::area() const
{
    return(length*height);
}

double Rectangle::perimeter() const
{

    return ( (height*3)+(length*3));
}

Point Rectangle::midPoint() const
{

    Point midPoint;
    double mpx = blPoint.getX() + 0.5 * length;
    double mpy = blPoint.getY() + 0.5 * height;
    midPoint.setX(mpx);
    midPoint.setY(mpy);
    return(midPoint);
}

void Rectangle::scaleBy3()
{
    double mx = blPoint.getX() + 0.5 * length;
    double my = blPoint.getY() + 0.5 * height;
    double newmdx = mx - length;
    double newmdy = my - height;
    length= 3* length;
    height = 3* height;
    blPoint.setX(newmdx);
    blPoint.setY(newmdy);
}

void Rectangle::display() const
{
    cout << " Location is (" << blPoint.getX() << ", " << blPoint.getY() << "), length is " << length << ", height is " << height << "; Area is " << area() << "; perimeter is " << perimeter() << ", midpoint is located at (" << midPoint().getX() << ", " << midPoint().getY() << ")" << endl;
}
```

The output needs to be

```
Enter the name of the first rectangle: rec hi
Enter hi's bottom left x and y coords: 1 1
Enter hi's length and height: 2 2

Thank you! Enter the name of the next rectangle: stop

You have 1 rectangle(s) in your list:

Rectangle 'hi': Location is (1, 1), Length is 2, Height is 2; Area is 4, Perimeter is 8, Midpoint is located at (2, 2)
     After scale by 3: Location is (-1, -1), Length is 6, Height is 6; Area is 36, Perimeter is 24, Midpoint is located at (2, 2)
```

but right the output is

```
Enter the name of the first rectangle: rec hi
Enter hi's bottom left x and y coords: 1 1
Enter hi's length and height: 2 2

Thank you! Enter the name of the next rectangle: Invalid input. Type 'rec' following by the name or 'stop' if done.
Try again! 
Enter the name of the next rectangle: stop
You have 1 rectangle(s) in your list: 
Rectangle 'hi':  Location is (1, 1), length is 2, height is 2; Area is 4; perimeter is 12, midpoint is located at (2, 2)
After scale by 3: Location is (0, 0), length is 6, height is 6; Area is 36; perimeter is 36, midpoint is located at (3, 3)
```

I'd appreciate any help. I really don't want to pull another all nighter and I have most of it done! Thanks so much!

Comment: This is too much code to go through to figure out where the problem is. Please consider posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also note that when you scale a rectangle, you have to decide which point of the rectangle remains unchanged. Is it the lower left corner, is it the upper right corner, is it the mid point? Without that, there are infinite possible ways to scale a rectangle.

Comment: Sorry I just created an account today. I believe the problem lies within my nested loops in the int main(). - the rectangle is scaled by 3 about its midpoint if that helps at all. Just reading from my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to scale a `Rectangle` by mid point, then the logic in your function is incorrect. Try this:

```
void Rectangle::scaleBy3()
{
    double mx = blPoint.getX() + 0.5 * length;
    double my = blPoint.getY() + 0.5 * height;

    length = 3 * length;
    height = 3 * height;

    // Mid point remains exactly at the same location.
    // Move the lower left corner so that it is offset from
    // the mid point by half the length and half the width.
    blPoint.setX( mx - 0.5*length);
    blPoint.setY( my - 0.5*height);
}
```

**Update**

The logic you are using to read name is problematic. Take a look at [How to allow user to do input more than twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463056/how-to-allow-user-to-do-input-more-than-twice/24463083#24463083)

Comment: Yea realized I had messed a bit in the logic. Thanks, but I am still have trouble with my bool functions. If you notice in what I had said in my original question my current program will output "Invalid Input" and "Try again!" when the user will have valid inputs. Im not sure what is causing this in my while loops in the main or if it is the bool function itself.